# Out-of-core matrix transpose of row compressed data

Tags: matrix

Summary: Are there good algorithms for out-of-core dense matrix transpose if each row of the matrix is separately compressed?

Details: The matrix is about 1 TB uncompressed, and is roughly but not exactly square.  An uncompressed row is less than 6 MB, so many of them fit in RAM at once.  On disk, I would like to separately compress each row of the matrix (with a domain-specific, non-random access method), so I need a transpose algorithm that reads from compressed form, recompresses each column, and writes out the compressed columns as the new transposed matrix.

Are any existing out-of-core transpose algorithms compatible with this setup?

Comment: How are you compressing the matrix?

Comment: Each row can be reinterpreted as a rank 6 bit tensor.  I haven't implemented it yet, but the plan is to apply a filter/prediction step to increase the number of zeros, then run it through zlib (similar to png compression).

Comment: Why do you want to store individual (compressed) rows instead of compressed tiles?

Comment: Because the rest of the computation works most naturally by streaming the data through row by row.  It isn't actually a linear algebraic matrix: it's an 8 dimensional bit array of win/loss values for a set of pentago positions.  Viewed as a two dimensional array, the access pattern of the computational kernel is semirandom within each row, but doesn't jump between rows.

Comment: Okay, but you can hold several rows in memory while generating them, and maybe you even create them in parallel (threads or MPI). Putting it on disk in tiles gives up cheap single-row access, but it will make column access massively faster.

Comment: Yeah, that's very true.  I can hold something like 500-700 uncompressed rows in memory at a time, and square tiles of that size are plenty large enough to amortize disk access.  And then no need to ever form the transpose on disk.  Cool, I should be all set.

Comment: @JedBrown: Could you gather your comments into an answer? I think the solution you proposed is probably the best one given so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need fast random access to single rows, you can store tiles instead of storing rows. For example, generate $500$ rows at a time and store them in $500\times 500$ tiles (match to a disk block size for best possible performance). These tiles are big enough that reading them off the disk in a different order (e.g. by columns) will still perform well.

Comment: Matching to disk block size is hard due to the compression, but otherwise this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement it using blocks of rows. If the matrix is $A$, write it as a sum $A=\sum_{b=1}^B A_b$ where each block $A_b$ consists of only some of the rows of $A$. You choose each block to be so that it fits into memory.

Then $A^T=\sum_{b=1}^B A_b^T$: compute the transpose of $A_1$, store it to disk. Read $A_2$, compute its transpose and add the new columns you get from $A_2^T$ to the ones already computed for $A_1^T$, and so on and so forth. As long as you can store $A_b^T$ and the compressed form of the already treated transposes, it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.  You can't simply write $A_b^T$ to disk independently of the other $A_b^T$, since it needs to be woven into the compressed rows of the output transposed matrix.

Comment: Yes, but every row of $A^T$ is a compressed list of column indices and corresponding values, and you can of course write a partial list to disk, later load it again and merge it with another list.

Comment: Ah, that explains the mismatch: the matrix is dense.  Doing the repeated load and merge on a dense matrix would result in a massive amount of extra I/O.

Comment: Oh, I misread your original statement then. I thought it was compressed, and I had imagined that you had sparsified it.